# Eclipse show only proposed methods (single window)

Tags: eclipse

How do I remove second window on the right from proposals? Always that proposals are displayed also second window appears. That is not convenient because it takes focus.

[image]

Comment: Using plain Windows 10 I can not reproduce this problem. Only if I explicitly click on the yellow JavaDoc window my focus changes. Are you sure you have not installed a tool (some mouse tool) that is responsible for the focus change?

Comment: Hi Robert, Yes I'm using Brille display and I'm using it on Mac (on Windows I don't experience that). After second window appears I can't close it and I can't get to the list of methods. I guess the best would be not to show it at all.

Comment: If you meant "Braille", then this is an accessibility bug that needs to be reported in Bugzilla at http://bugs.eclipse.org/ .